# Model design on alternative ingredients name

Tags: django, database-design, model

I am creating a simple application that captures the name of a product along with their respective ingredients. I have 2 models defined in my Django app for that

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    # 1 ingredient belongs to many products. 
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
```

As I was looking at random products and their ingredients, I noticed that there are alternative names of to an ingredient. For example, certain manufacturers would put water as, aqua, h2o, eau, purified water, distilled water and so on.

How can I best write a model that is able to capture these alternative names in an efficient manner?

I thought of putting in additional fields such as

```
    alternativeName1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    alternativeName2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    alternativeName3 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

But it doesn't seem like a good application design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a ***Variation***  model having foreign of ***Ingredient*** model, name and manufacturer information. This means you have many variations of a ingredient

```
class Variation(models.Model):
   ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, related_name="variations")
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
```

So in future if there are more names for any ingredient you can easily keep it.

Or alternatively you can add a [***`JSONField()`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) to Ingredient model

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
   ...
   # add json field and keep all name and manufacturer detail in dictionary
   # [{'name':'aqua', 'manufacturer':'vendor name'},{},...]
   data = JSONField()
```